# python strange matplotlib behavior of toolbar

Tags: matplotlib, button, properties, toolbar

A very simple question. In python -3, ver.10 I build the same simple graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [1, 5, 3, 5, 7, 8]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

On computer #I  I see plot with a rich top-places toolbar (#1) with 8 buttons (Fig.1), but on computer #2  I see a bottom-placed toolbar (#2) with only 7 buttons (Fig.2). The default functionality of the toolbar (#1) and the toolbar (#2) is different. Why? How can I fix this strange matplotlib behavior so that the property of toolbar would be the same in all cases?

[image: top-placed toolbar]

[image: bottom-placed toolbar]

Comment: They will be using different [backends](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/users/explain/backends.html)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: computer #1 has pyqt5 installed and computer #2 does not. After installing pip [pip install pyqt5] on computer #2, the same toolbar menu appeared in Fig. 2 as in Fig. 1. Moreover, after installing pyqt5, the addcopyfighandler package (import addcopyfighandler) starts working on computer #2 in the same way as on computer #1. The last question was asked in my other post. So, both problems are solved by installing pyqt5.